# Как увеличить шрифт в редакторе Nano

Tags: linux, archlinux, manjaro

Версия nano:

GNU nano, version 3.1

Версия Линукс : 
Manjaro Community Editions Bspwm (18.0.0)

LSB Version:    n/a
Distributor ID: ManjaroLinux 
Description:    Manjaro Linux
Release:        18.0.0
Codename:       Illyria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Шрифт редакторе `nano` совпадает со шрифтом в консоли в которой он запущен. Так что единственный выход поменять шрифт в своём эмуляторе терминала/виртуальной консоли/vga-адаптере/экране своего векторного дисплея.

Comment: название терминала в самом верху 1:bash*  - запускаю командой win+z, терминал bash

Comment: пробовал менять xterm -fa ‘Monospace’ -fa 12 , увеличиваем шрифт терминала временно, не помогает

Comment: @ДенисЛатыпов, `bash` — это командная оболочка. а не терминал.... Раз способ для `xterm`'а не помогает, то вероятно ты пользуешься другим эмулятором терминала... ЗЫ: если он относительно новый и без особых претензий, то вероятно, шрифт будет настраиваться где-то в его меню...

Comment: sterminal -v, st 0.8.1, походу оно

Comment: может быть тут менять в этом конфиге.Xdefaults ? или vconsole.conf

Comment: cat /etc/vconsole.conf
KEYMAP=us
FONT=ter-116n
он мне выдал, 116 это не разммер шрифта, это сам шрифт

Comment: @ДенисЛатыпов, судя по всему это настройка над [st](https://st.suckless.org/), так что поздравляю — это терминал с претензиями, который подразумевает. что пользователь как минимум умеет читать документацию, а также желательно должен понимать, как программы запускаются... так что предлагаю начать с прочтения `man st` ...

Comment: читаю man st : CUSTOMIZATION
       st can be customized by creating a custom config.h and (re)compiling the source code. This keeps it fast, secure and simple.

Comment: Т.е. посути в файле config.h. размер шрифта

Comment: вот в github нашел https://github.com/ctjhoa/st/blob/master/config.h  прям первые строки static char *font = "DejaVu Sans Mono:size=8";

Comment: а где на самой системе он лежит не понятно

Comment: whereis st
st: /usr/bin/st /usr/share/st /usr/share/man/man4/st.4.gz /usr/share/man/man1/st.1.gz

Answer (score 0):

способ меняет размер шрифта редактора nano и консоль sterminal

набираем команду в консоли

```
sudo nano ~/.sterminalrc
```

содержимое файла :

```
#!/bin/dash
#~/.sterminalrc
# see man st for possible options to set.
export font="Terminus:size=18"
```

выбираем вот эту строку `export font="Terminus:size=18"`
и ее меняем где

```
size=ваш_размер_шрифта
```